# Depth of n-ary tree OCaml

Tags: tree, functional-programming, ocaml, depth

I had to calculate the depth of a n-ary tree in OCaml using only functional paradigm whitout the use of external homemade function. Here's the struc :

```
type nTree = 
  Id of int
  | Leaf of string
  | Tree of string * string * nTree list
```

and here is my result :

```
  let rec height t = match t with
     | Id _ -> 0
     | Leaf _ -> 0
     | Tree(_,_,n) -> if n = [] then 1
                      else let e::r = n in max 
                      (List.fold_left (fun acc x -> acc + height x) 1 [e])
                      (List.fold_left (fun acc x -> acc + height x) 1 r)
```

It work but I find it very ugly and the `e::r` bit cause a warning because of not matching the `[]` pattern.
Is there a way to make this warning free and "prettier" ?

Thx!

Comment: Why are you summing the heights of all the child trees?

Comment: Because I need them ? for example Tree("a", "b", [Tree("c", "d", [Tree("e", "f",[Leaf("f")]; Leaf("g")]; Id(2); Tree("h", "i", [])], should return 3 because the first tree has a max level of 2 Tree in it. Maybe my question was not correctly formulate or there is something I don't grasp.

Comment: No, I'm asking why you are *summing* them. Sure you need them all, but what do you do to get the *depth* of the current node?

Comment: Yeah I guess there is something I don't understand in the recursive because your answer is correct. I just assumed that a I needed them otherwise all the Tree would have count in the height of the tree. My first try was something like that : | Tree(_,_,n) -> List.fold_left (fun x y -> x + height y) 1 n. And it was summing all the tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the `e::r` bit causes a warning because of not matching the `[]` pattern

You'd just use pattern matching instead of `if`:

```
match n with
  | [] -> 1
  | e::r -> …
```

But actually there's no point in distinguishing these at all. You should be doing

```
  let rec height = function
     | Id _ -> 0
     | Leaf _ -> 0
     | Tree(_,_,n) -> 1 + List.fold_left max 0 (List.map height n)
```